# Button Color Issue

Tags: javascript, html, button

I am new to Javascript and trying to learn the language.
I don't yet know CSS or jquery.
I plan to eventually learn but one language at a time, I am not very bright.
I am trying to make a button that will auto shift colors based on the variable of growth.
I wish the button to start out green.
When variable growth is equal to or greater than evolution cost the buttons color should without any button clicking change to red.
When variable growth is less than evolution cost the buttons color should without any button clicking change to green.

With my coding as is the buttons color is black and won't change color no matter what.
I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Please explain any solutions so I can learn it.

This is the HTML section.

```
<p title="Click to gain evolution points to evolve your cell."><button type="button" class="btn" id="evolutionButton" onclick="buyEvolution()"><b>Evolve</b></button></p>
<p style="color:white" title="Evolution points are used to purchase evolutions.">Evolution: <span id="evolution">0</span></p>
<p style="color:white" title="Each additional Evolution point costs more growth to create.">Evolution Cost: <span id="evolutionCost">100</span></p>
```

**This is the Javascript section.**

```
var growth = 0;
function GrowthClick(number){
    growth = growth + number;
    document.getElementById("growth").innerHTML = growth;
};

var evolution = 0;

function buyEvolution(){
    var evolutionCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(2,evolution));
    if(growth >= evolutionCost){
        evolution = evolution + 1;
        growth = growth - evolutionCost;
        document.getElementById('evolution').innerHTML = evolution;
        document.getElementById('growth').innerHTML = growth;
    };
    var nextCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(2,evolution));
    document.getElementById('evolutionCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
};

var evolutionButton;

function colorEvolution(){
    if (growth >= evolutionCost {     
        document.getElementById("evolutionButton").className = "red"; 
    } else {
        document.getElementById("evolutionButton").className = "green";
    }
    document.getElementById('growth').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('evolutionCost').innerHTML;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a switch statement for this leave it outside of the functions but this should be able to change the color of your button based off the value of the growth variable.

```
switch(growth){
case 0:
    document.getElementById("evolutionButton").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    break;
case 1:
    document.getElementById("evolutionButton").style.backgroundColor = "Yellow";
    break;
case 2:
    document.getElementById("evolutionButton").style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    break;
case 3:
    document.getElementById("evolutionButton").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    break;
case 4:
    document.getElementById("evolutionButton").style.backgroundColor = "purple";
}
```

I see that you're trying to change the color by changing its class name here
`{document.getElementById("evolutionButton").className = "green";}`
but i believe the switch statement would be easier

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped me in another site by teaching me new programming aspects.
I then wrote this and it worked.

HTML

```
    <p title="Click to gain evolution points to evolve your cell."><button type="button" id="evolutionButton" onclick="buyEvolution()"><b>Evolve</b></button></p>
    <p style="color:white" title="Evolution points are used to purchase evolutions.">Evolution: <span id="evolution">0</span></p>
    <p style="color:white" title="Each additional Evolution point costs more growth to create.">Evolution Cost: <span id="evolutionCost">100</span></p>
```

Javascript

```
var growth = 0;

function updateGrowth() {
document.getElementById('growth').innerHTML = growth;
colorEvolution();
};

function GrowthClick(number){
growth = growth + number;
updateGrowth();
};

var evolution = 0;

function updateEvolution() {
document.getElementById('evolution').innerHTML = evolution;
};

var evolutionCost;

function buyEvolution(){
evolutionCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(2,evolution));
if(growth >= evolutionCost){
    evolution = evolution + 1;
    growth = growth - evolutionCost;
    updateEvolution();
    updateGrowth();
};
var nextEvolution = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(2,evolution));
document.getElementById('evolutionCost').innerHTML = nextEvolution;
};

function colorEvolution(){
var evolutionColor = document.getElementById("evolutionButton");
evolutionCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(2,evolution));
if (growth >= evolutionCost) {evolutionColor.style.color = "red";}
else {evolutionColor.style.color = "green";}
};
```